# Programming with pcap example

Tags: c, endianness, pcap, libpcap

I'm learning with libpcap from this http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html and I've run into problem with this code:

```
struct sniff_ethernet {
    u_char ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Destination host address */
    u_char ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN]; /* Source host address */
    u_short ether_type; /* IP? ARP? RARP? etc */
};
```

...

```
const struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet; /* The ethernet header */
ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(packet);
```

I'm getting ether_type values with swapped bytes. I think the reason is that I'm using x86_64 little-endian machine where LSB is at lowest address and in the packet byte stream the ether_type MSB is before LSB. The question is: is the example code working on big-endian machine only or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code at http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html is not looking at the Ethernet type, so it works regardless of the byte order of the machine on which it's running.  It's relying on the capture filter ("port 23") not to capture non-IPv4 traffic.

You'll have to, for example, use `ntohs()` on the `ether_type` field when you use its value in your code.

Comment: I didn't know `ntohs()` and it solved my problem, to detect 802.1Q tagged frames so thank you!